# Drawing dividers between different colors in a segmented colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

[image]

I would like to draw black horizontal dividers between the different individual colors in the segmented colorbar.

**mcve**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm

plt.plot() # dummy Axes

nmin, N = 0, 11
bounds = [nmin-0.5]+[n+0.5 for n in range(nmin, N)]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, 256)
cm = plt.get_cmap('cool')

cb = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm, cm), format='%02d', ax=plt.gca())
cb.set_ticks(range(nmin, N))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my method with the function [axhline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) in a for loop, you can adjust the lines with the arguments in the doc :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm

plt.plot() # dummy Axes

nmin, N = 0, 11
bounds = [nmin-0.5]+[n+0.5 for n in range(nmin, N)]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, 256)
cm = plt.get_cmap('cool')

cb = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm, cm), format='%02d', ax=plt.gca())
cax = cb.ax
for bound in bounds:
    cax.axhline(bound, c='k', linewidth=0.4)
cb.set_ticks(range(nmin, N))

plt.show()
```

Figure:
[image]

Comment: `linewidth=0.67`